# Install Bootstrap 5 DataTables using npm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, npm-install, bootstrap-5

How can I install Bootstrap 5 with data tables using npm? I know for Bootstrap 4 you can use the following.

```
npm install datatables.net-bs4
```

Instead, I tried:

```
npm install datatables.net-bs
```

Does anyone know how to install Bootstrap 5 DataTables?

Answer (score 4):

Just tried installing datatables bootstrap 5 support via npm, and it looks like it's available.

```
npm install datatables.net-bs5
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can use the CDNs for the DataTables Bootstrap 5 integration.

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js
```

Comment: Ok. So as of now, there is no option using npm. Right?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be since DataTables are calling it a "Preview)" version.
"At the time of writing this example, Bootstrap 5 is at 5.0.0-alpha.1, and therefore might yet change. This [example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html) shows our current integration with Bootstrap 5, which will evolve as Bootstrap 5 does."